# Error while importing VM in virtual box

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I am trying to import Windows VM in virtualbox.

My config is: Mac OS X 10.6.8, RAM - 2048

I am getting error

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Windows XP Professional With Firefox.

Failed to load VMMR0.r0 (VERR_SUPLIB_WORLD_WRITABLE).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Console
Interface: IConsole {1968b7d3-e3bf-4ceb-99e0-cb7c913317bb}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for above problem.

Go to your Disk Utility in MAC --> Burn --> Select your HD and click on Repair disk permissions.

Above steps solved my problem.

[image: Refer the image]Thanks, virtualbox.org